# Facebook Request Dialog - For a Mobile App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

Is it possible to display FACEBOOK REQUEST DIALOG in mobile apps. 
As for as I have looked, most people say REQUEST DIALOGS are available only for Canvas Apps.
But the docs page
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/
says

> If you have built a Canvas or Mobile Web application, Requests are a
>   great way to enable users to invite their friends to use your app.

So Is it possible. i tried the URL method mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

The dialog opens. But even after I select a friend and send app request,   the friend doesn't get my request.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or Is it not possible to user request dialogs with Mobile apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to also says:

> Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas apps and not websites. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

The wording "Desktop Canvas apps" seems pretty unambiguous in excluding mobile native client apps and mobile web apps.  So I think it is not supported.

Comment: Hmm. It actually makes sense to require a Canvas URL; where else will the user be directed on clicking on the app request?

I tried with a dummy canvas URL and IT ACTUALLY WORKED!

Not using it though! I make do with some other workarounds.

THANKS anyway!

Comment: Out of date: "Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas, iOS and Android apps."  Also, that page is incorrect--http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/ says "Canvas or Mobile Web application", and requests work fine for web apps.

Comment: (They appear to be very broken on iOS, though.)